# Attempt to present UIAlertController on UITabBarController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview

I have a timer in my app delegate, the user choose the time interval needed to execute the selector of that timer in another viewController that is not in the tab bar; after choosing the time interval a modal segue is used to load the first viewController in the UITabBarController

when the time interval passes I want the app to present an alert but it gives me this: Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController on UITabBarController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

here is the code that I'am using :

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "alert", message: "test", preferredStyle: .Alert)
self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try to get visible view controller. You can do this with this public extension:

```
 public extension UIWindow {
    public var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {
        return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(self.rootViewController)
    }

    public static func getVisibleViewControllerFrom(vc: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        if let nc = vc as? UINavigationController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(nc.visibleViewController)
        } else if let tc = vc as? UITabBarController {
            return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(tc.selectedViewController)
        } else {
            if let pvc = vc?.presentedViewController {
                return UIWindow.getVisibleViewControllerFrom(pvc)
            } else {
                return vc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then show alert controller in this vc

Comment: What about a uisplitviewcontroller in a uitabbarcontroller?